# Rust Ownership Smart Pointers

Tags: rust

I've recently started learning Rust and just learned about the Smart Pointers (`Box`, `Rc` and `RefCell`).

In the guide they talked about `Rc` implementing "shared ownership". But if I understood it correctly, the whole point of the ownership system is that there can only be one owner.

And to me (still a Rust newbie) it seems as if `Rc` and `RefCell` take ownership of they value they contain and just "expose" different types of references to the contained value?

Am I wrong and if yes: why is Rust allowed to "cheat" the ownership system like that and would I be theoretically able to implement my own "cheating" types?

Comment: They use unsafe under the hood. That's all.

Comment: You simply cannot program some things without having these "cheats". But they're tested and reliable to use, so their "cheating" nature doesn't cause much trouble. In general, Rust doesn't prohibit you from making fast and convenient tools by breaking normal rules via `unsafe`. But unless you're sure they're working bug-less you should be very very careful

Comment: The ownership system is not cheated by `Rc` and `RefCell` because they offer the same guarantees provided by normal types. You still can't get more than one mutable reference at a time, and you still cannot obtain a shared reference if a mutable reference to the same value is active. You won't be able to incur undefined behavior (memory corruption, uncontrolled crashes or miscompilations) in safe Rust using these types. The only difference is that they move the checks from compile time to run time, thus enabling safe access to the shared-ownership idiom which would otherwise be inaccessible.

Answer (score 5):

> if I understood it correctly, the whole point of the ownership system is that there can only be one owner.

No. Rust guarantees that there can be no more than a single *mutable borrow* and there cannot be mutable and non-mutable borrows at the same time. It doesn't say anything about owners.

> why is Rust allowed to "cheat" the ownership system

It doesn't.

> would I be theoretically able to implement my own "cheating" types

Yes. Those types are all implemented in Rust¹. Those types are battle-tested and perfectly safe under Rust's safety rules, but they require the use of `unsafe` at a lower level.

Note that `unsafe` doesn't permit going around the rule that you can have one mutable borrow XOR any number of non-mutable borrows, but using unsafe, you *could* do it anyway. This, of course, would actually be unsafe (and trigger undefined behavior).

---

1: Although some of those types are implemented using features that are still private to the compiler so you wouldn't be able to do everything as efficiently as the standard library, and `Box` and `UnsafeCell` are special to the language and cannot be reproduced by a normal library. There are for example many crates providing `Rc` or `Arc` alternatives which are better that the standard ones in some cases.

Comment: It does say "There can only be one owner at a time."